# How to fill with nearest neighbor pixel in some missing pixels on c++ here is my code

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

```
int depth_i=1,depth_j=1;
for(depth_i=1;depth_i<DepthShow.rows;depth_i++)
    {
        unsigned char * pixel_depth = DepthShow.ptr<unsigned char>(depth_i);

        for(depth_j=1;depth_j<DepthShow.cols;depth_j++)
            {
            if(pixel_depth[depth_j]==0) //*
                        pixel_depth[depth_j]=500;   //*
            }
    }
```

I am using kinect sensor and opencv
in commented lines //* if 1*1 pixel is missing then fills value of 500. I want to fill with nearest neighbor pixel instead of 500.

Some one help me to apply   Nearest neighbor pixel on c++

Comment: Defining nearest neighbor will help yourself.

Comment: you need to define the problem better.  If a point is 500 and none of the points around it are, which is its nearest neighbor?  If all the points used to be 500 but have been filled with their nearest neighbors, who is its nearest neighbor.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am using 480*640 pixels, Suppose that 1*1's pixel is missing, So I wanna fill this pixel with nearest neighbor pixel.Such as 1*2 or 2*1 or 2*2. 
if this pixels are also missing, Go to next step, such as 1*3,2*3,3*1,3*2,3*3 so on,,,

How to define nearest neighbor ?

Comment: As far as I understand, you have got a matrix with positive values and missing "== 0" values and you want to infer missing values from adjacent pixels values. Is it correct? I am confuse with the "500" value... Where does it come from ?
I never worked with kinect, but you should be capable of considering your depth map as a grey-scale image and use approaches like morphological dilatation, floodfill (or why not inpainting)... on it.

Comment: @Bayanaa: You tell us. This is a site to answer programming questions, such as "Given this mathematical definition of NN, how do I calculate it in C++? Here's my attempt." But you seem to miss even the mathematical definition, so we cannot match that to C++ code.

Comment: @ Quentin Geissmann, thanks  your attention.That is correct. 500 is just random number.I want to fill "==0" values neighbor pixel instead of 500, pls don't care about 500, you can imagine that 500 is neigbor pixel value. morphological and inpainting approaches are not robust.